# readd answer to question

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

During rewieving the first post queue i saw following question:

[SCCM - Find where collections are referenced](https://serverfault.com/questions/797462/sccm-find-where-collections-are-referenced)

There was a link only answer which i tried to comment on to help the user understand how to include links.

Here is the slot in the queue i was reviewing:

https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/309899

So far nothing unusual.

However the answer itself was already deleted but another comment showed me that it might actually have answered the OPs question.

While the answer was not good (link only), now the question has neither an answer nor any help at all.

So i suggest to undelete the answer or have the answer rewritten if undeleting is impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not have sufficient privileges yet to see that the answer was converted to a comment by one of my fellow moderators, rather than deleted outright.

The content was preserved but since it is both phrased as question and a link-only-answer it is not a *good* answer.
Converting such low quality answers to comments is something only moderators can do and is something we regularly need to because new low-rep users are not yet granted the [privilege to comment](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment) and are therefor required to post their suggestions as answers.

[image: converted to comment]